Javascript - Attemp to replace document.execCommand with my own style function in contenteditable=true element
Ok im trying to make my own rich text editor. This is my function :
/**
 * Apply Style
 *
 * @param selectedRange
 * @param tag
 */
function applyStyle(selectedRange, tag) {

    const selectedFragment = selectedRange.extractContents();

    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        selectedFragment,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        { acceptNode: (node) => NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT }
    );

    let currentNode = walker.nextNode();

    /**
     * Toggle Style
     *
     * @param node
     */
    const toggle = (node) => {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            const parent = node.parentNode;
            if (parent.nodeName === tag) {
                const nextSibling = node.nextSibling;
                parent.parentNode.insertBefore(node, parent);
                parent.remove();
                if (nextSibling && parent.parentNode) {
                    parent.parentNode.insertBefore(nextSibling, parent);
                }
            } else {
                const newNode = document.createElement(tag.toLowerCase());
                node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node);
                newNode.appendChild(node);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Walking the current node
     */
    while (currentNode) {
        toggle(currentNode);
        currentNode = walker.nextNode();
    }

    /**
     * Insert the new Node
     */
    selectedRange.insertNode(selectedFragment);

    /**
     * Find all Current tags
     *
     * @type {HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[string]>}
     */
    let currentTags = document.getElementsByTagName(tag.toLowerCase());

    /**
     * Iterate all tags
     */
    for (let i = currentTags.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const currentTag = currentTags[i];
        if (currentTag.textContent.trim().length === 0) {
            currentTag.parentNode.removeChild(currentTag);
        }
    }
}

This function works well except for one detail. I'm trying to apply the same style to text that already has a style, for example <strong>, <em>, <u>; it should remove the style. It works fine if I keep the text selection, but if I deselect and then reselect the text, for some reason it adds an additional nested element.
The problem I see is that in the "toggle" function, this line doesn't get the parent element of the node when reselecting the same text: const parent = node.parentNode;
example how to use the function :
const selection = window.getSelection();
const selectedRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);

applyStyle(selectedRange, 'STRONG');

What could I do to achieve this?
